# Inserting collection as Rows in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra. I have a scenario where I will be sending a collection of objects to be saved. For example, a person and his contacts. If I have to use something like

```
public boolean addContacts(String personId, Collection<Contact> contacts){
        // My Cassandra code to save this collection as individual rows (bulk execution)
        return false;
```

Cassandra batch expects a series of queries that can be executed in a batch. But for that will have to loop through and construct the queries. So, is there a way to avoid the looping of collection or optimize it?
I came accross executeBulk for the same kind of scenario in Couch DB.

Answer (score 0):

What you first have to decide is the schema. To create an schema you have to analyze the queries you want to support.

If you want to store and retrieve contacts per person, it could be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
  person_id text,
  email text,
  name text
  phone text,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id, email)
)
```

*(Its a simplified schema, you should choose identifiers accordingly, I'm just making a working sample)*

In this way, the contacts will be partitioned by person_id and clustered by a second key, in this case the email.

If you need to insert contacts in batches you can do it using the [Datastax java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

You will have to iterate through the contacts like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (person_id, email, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
//for each contact, bind the parameters
for (Contact c : contacts) {
  batch.add(ps.bind(personId, c.email, c.name, c.phone));
}
session.execute(batch);
```